# NodeJS: How to run code when any page is loaded in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have tried to do this, so i can check the url with an array to redirect it to an error page. But i dont know how to run code when a page is loaded.

Ive tried looking it up everywhere, but to no avail

Comment: You can write your own [Express middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) if you want some function to run for every request.

Comment: and how might i do that? As in, how would i check for requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `app.use` to do something every time a page is loaded.

```
const app = require('express')();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // For example, a GET request to `/test` will print "GET /test"
  console.log(`${req.method} ${req.url}`);

  next();
});

app.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('ok');
});

// Test the above app using Axios
const server = await app.listen(3000);

const axios = require('axios');
// Prints "get /test"
const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/test');
```

See this documenation for more info. https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/express/app-use